# Accessing httparty API results in ruby

Tags: ruby, api, hash

I'm trying to access the API results from HTTParty, but can't figure out how...I've stored the results in a variable called zillow that looks like the following:

```
=> {"searchresults"=>
  {"request"=>{"address"=>"49 Alpine Way", "citystatezip"=>"28805"},
   "message"=>{"text"=>"Request successfully processed", "code"=>"0"},
   "response"=>
    {"results"=>
      {"result"=>
        {"zpid"=>"5628657",
         "links"=>
          {"homedetails"=>"http://www.zillow.com/homedetails/49-Alpine-Way-Asheville-NC-28805/5628657_zpid/",
           "graphsanddata"=>"http://www.zillow.com/homedetails/49-Alpine-Way-Asheville-NC-28805/5628657_zpid/#charts-and-data",
           "mapthishome"=>"http://www.zillow.com/homes/5628657_zpid/",
           "comparables"=>"http://www.zillow.com/homes/comps/5628657_zpid/"},
         "address"=>
          {"street"=>"49 Alpine Way",
           "zipcode"=>"28805",
           "city"=>"Asheville",
```

I'm trying to access "zpid" but keep getting nil as a response.  I've tried the following:

```
[107] pry(main)> zillow["searchresults"]["zpid"]
=> nil
[108] pry(main)> zillow["zpid"]
=> nil
[109] pry(main)> zillow["searchresults"]["results"]["zpid"]
NoMethodError: undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass
from (pry):100:in `<main>'
[110] pry(main)> zillow.find["zpid"]
NoMethodError: undefined method `[]' for #<Enumerator:0x0000000323b3f8>
from (pry):101:in `<main>'
[111] pry(main)> zillow.get["zpid"]
NoMethodError: undefined method `get' for #<HTTParty::Response:0x00000003adb0f8>
from /home/pjw/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/httparty-0.14.0/lib/httparty/response.rb:85:in `method_missing'
[112] pry(main)> zillow["searchresults"]
=> {"request"=>{"address"=>"49 Alpine Way", "citystatezip"=>"28805"},
 "message"=>{"text"=>"Request successfully processed", "code"=>"0"},
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You missed a chain of keys to get `zpid`

```
zillow["searchresults"]["response"]["results"]["result"]["zpid"]
```

If you on ruby 2.3.0 then you can use [Hash#dig](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0_preview1/Hash.html#method-i-dig) method

Comment: Wow, THANK YOU!!!!  I'm still new to Ruby and spent about two hours trying to figure that out....I figured it was something easy....:-)  Thanks again.